# If socket is not yet accepted, is the master socket still socket_select-able?

Tags: php, sockets

I'm now studying a php websockets server implementation to write a new one.

Here is the part to accept new connections:

```
$write = [];
$except = [];
while(isset(self::$read[0])){
    $changed = self::$read;
    $result = socket_select($changed, $write, $except, 1);
    if($result === false){
        // Error handling
    }elseif($result > 0){
        foreach($changed as $clientID => $socket){
            if($clientID != 0){
                // Read bytes
            }else{
                $client = socket_accept(self::$read[0]);
                if($client !== false){
                    // Add client
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Ping idle clients
}
```

where `self::$read[0]` is the master socket listening for new connections.

I haven't (and currently unable to) test this thoroughly but if there are multiple incoming new connections within that one second, wouldn't the `socket_accept` only accept one of them? Would the `socket_select` select the master socket again on the next iteration as there are still connection to be accepted?

Comment: i don't see how its possible to accept more than one connection without using a thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, socket_accept() returns only one connection. We can call the select in a loop, and if there are more connections (aka read event for the listener/server fd), then the select would return immediately. TCP maintains a separate queue for connections that are not accepted yet (also called pending connections).